# How to find which field in my CSV file appears the most using a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix

I'm learning how to use Shell script and I have a CSV file containing 5 columns `name forname telephone room email` and I want to find which `room`contains the most persons.

For the moment I did the following code and I'm stuck at the part where I need to count which room has the more employee or which room appear the most in the file

```
input="x.csv"
while read line; do
    room=$(echo $line | cut -d \; -f 4)
    if [ -n "$room" ]; then

    fi
done < ${input}
```

Comment: Can you include sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting the occurances of unique values is probably done best by using `uniq -c`.
So to count the entries for each room individually, you need to extract a list which contains the column `room`. `awk` is probably the best tool in the bash environment to do that.
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="x.csv"

awk '{print $4}' $input | sort | uniq -c
```

this will return a list with two columns. The first column contains the number of occurences of the respective value in column two, such as:

```
      4 room1b
      2 room1
      1 room2
      1 room3
```

For more complex analysis follow [Corentin's lead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58482792/12063049) to extend `awk`'s input.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing csv files like this is painful.

Use [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) :

```
awk -F';' '# CSV delimiter set to ;
    $4{ # This block will be executed if room value is not null
        n_persons[$4] += 1
        if (n_persons[$4] > max){
            max = n_persons[$4] #current max of employees per room
            room_max = $4 #current room that has most employees
        }
    }
    END{#this block is executed after reading the file
        print room_max
    }
' <file>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the input and for linking awk !

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using Bash, it has [associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html). I am not entirely sure how you would sort those in plain bash and using only bash sounds a bit complicated for this. Perhaps `awk` would work better?

In Bash instead of the original approach I would do this with a piping of:

1. `cut` (to select the column, as you've already done)
2. `sort` (to sort the values so they can be processed with `uniq`)
3. `uniq -c` (to count the number of occurances of a single column value)
4. `sort -nr` (to sort by the number of occurances, descending order -- greatest first)
5. `head` (to get only the most frequent occurance)

Something along the lines of (untested):

```
cut -d \; -f 4 input.csv \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | sort -nr \
  | head -1
```

If you need to filter out some lines, I would add `grep -v` after `cut`. No need to use conditionals, while loops, `read` builtin. The `\` at the end of line tells bash that this "line" continues on the the next line.

The above is the what first occured to me. It can surely be optimized but then again, perhaps you should look for other programming languages or paradigms if this needs to be executed often and as fast as possible.

Comment: thank you for the great input on how works `cut, sort ...` it's really helpful !